# Jmeter scripts in VSTS - one will generate .csv and based on those results remaining .jmx files will continue execution

Tags: csv, jmeter, azure-devops, load-testing, azure-devops-rest-api

I created some jmeter scripts
1) will generate .csv file
2) remaining .jmx files uses the generated .csv files

How can i execute them in VSTS? - Please give me some suggestions. 
i tried using load test tab in VSTS, thats not working fine in my case

Comment: How do you do it through Jmeter?

Comment: By using JSR223 sampler, we can write the java code(thats for getting data from SQL and store it in .csv file)

Comment: Then, how do you base on the results remaining jmx files will contnue execution?

Comment: CSV Data Set Config - Refer that generated file in this and use that variable in the HTTP Request

Comment: What's the detail steps?